# How can i remove views inside of StackLayout?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a project. When i scan a barcode; its adding labels inside of stacklayout. But when i scan 2nd one its saving first labels, then adding 2nd one too. I must see just scanned one, not the 1st one. So how can i delete first labels then add new ones ?

```
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                kampanya.Children.Add(new Label
                {
                    Text = $"{myCampaignList[i].Name}",
                    TextColor = Color.FromHex("#22223b"),
                    FontSize = 22
                }); ;
```

Its my part of a code. When i scan its adding new label like this.

Comment: Why don't you use the existing one, and just change the Text property ? what is count ? could you clarify a bit more?

Comment: @Cfun because i taking datas from json file. And data numbers is always changing. For example in 1st barcode its create 10 label. Then another label its create 95 label. But when i scan 1st. then scan 2nd one its show me 10+95. I just need see 95.

Comment: `kampanya.Children.Remove()` or `kampanya.Children.Clear()`

Comment: @Cfun count is number of datas. So I creating that much label

Comment: Then you may clear all children before starting adding again in the second call `kampanya.Children.Clear()`

Comment: @Cfun and Jason Thank you brothers! It helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear all children of the `StackLayout` before start adding any:

```
 kampanya.Children.Clear()
 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
     kampanya.Children.Add(new Label
     {
         Text = $"{myCampaignList[i].Name}",
         TextColor = Color.FromHex("#22223b"),
         FontSize = 22
     });
}
```